# MSI installer with Silent or Passive mode will automatically restart computer without prompt for user sometimes

Tags: wix

Sometimes, when you install your MSI installer it will prompt user to restart computer, in this case if you are running in passive or silent mode, installer will automatically restart computer without any confirmation.

How can I solve this problem? Can I just make installer ignore this prompt and not restart computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid restarting computer, use `/norestart` flag

Comment: YES, I just see it. Thanks for your kindly help